# How to place data in item divider in ionic 5

Tags: angular, laravel, list, api, ionic-framework

i'm trying to place my data which im calling from API to the list which consist of ion-item-divider and below the actual content, i want to sort that data and place into the list according ion-item-divider. below is my code for reference.

**store.pages.ts**

```
    getAllStores(){
        this.dataservice.getAllStores().subscribe(res=>{
          this.data = res;
          console.log(this.data);
    
        })
      }
```

**store.page.html**

```
    <ion-content>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let obj of dataArray">
          <ion-col size="2">
            <ion-item-divider color="primary" (click)="filterPopover()">
              <ion-label class="ion-text-center">
                {{obj}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item-divider>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="10">
            <ion-list *ngFor="let store of data">
              <ion-item button>
                <img src="../assets/brand/1mg.png" alt="" width="60px" height="60px">
                <ion-label>
                  <div class="list-container">
                    <h1>{{store.title}}</h1>
                    <p>
                      <ion-icon name="gift"></ion-icon> Rs {{store.cback}} cashback
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you Please Explain more what Sorting you want? and also share your Sample Data.

Comment: [{title:abc, cback:2},{title:oiuts, cback:2},{title:sdcsd, cback:2},{title:iyert, cback:2},{title:ueruy, cback:2},{title:nbvc, cback:2}] this is sample data i just wanto to show like contact list means for e.g: A = abc, anhd, aied, B=byhfd, bkjhjhs, bjhdbsd. using ion-item-divider 'A' should come first then the data belogning to it come next when the data which is start from a are over then 'B' data should show @NajamUsSaqib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Sort your Array with `.sort()` function.

html:

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let obj of dataArray">
          <ion-col size="2">
            <ion-item-divider color="primary" (click)="filterPopover()">
              <ion-label class="ion-text-center">
                {{obj.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item-divider>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col size="10">
            <ion-list *ngFor="let store of dataArray">
              <ion-item button>
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png" alt="" width="60px" height="60px">
                <ion-label>
                  <div class="list-container">
                    <h1>{{store.title}}</h1>
                    <p>
                      <ion-icon name="gift"></ion-icon> Rs {{store.cback}} cashback
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
```

.ts

```
this.yourDataFromApi = [
      {title:"abc", cback:2},
      {title:"oiuts", cback:2},
      {title:"sdcsd", cback:2},
      {title:"iyert", cback:2},
      {title:"ueruy", cback:2},
      {title:"nbvc", cback:2}
    ];
    this.dataArray = this.yourDataFromApi.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
```

Comment: thank you so much for this solution, i solved it almost , i will try your solution also thanks for reply @NajamUsSaqib